Force on an iron core in a solenoid?
Consider the following textbook problem:

An iron core ($\mu_r > 1$) of length l is inserted into a solenoid with N turns of the same length, through which runs the DC current I, up to a length $0 \leq x \leq d$. Find the force exerted on the iron core.

The usual solution starts with the expression
$$U(x) = \frac{1}{2} L(x) I^2$$
for the energy "stored in the coil", where $L(x)$ is the inductance computed as
$$L(x) = \frac{\mu_0 N^2}{A\cdot{}l} \left(\frac{l-x}{l} + \mu_r\frac{x}{l}\right),$$
equating the solenoid with the partially inserted core with two solenoids in series of lengths $l-x$ and $x$, and computes the force as
$$F(x) = \frac{\partial U(x)}{\partial x} = L(0) (\mu_r - 1) \frac{x}{l}.$$
Now that's all fine, except that the sign is wrong: indeed it should be $F(x) = -\frac{\partial U(x)}{\partial x}$, i.e. the energy $U(x)$ increases when $x$ increases from 0 to positive values, so by the principle of virtual work the iron core would experience not a force pulling it in but a force pushing the core out.
However, a solenoid really does pull an iron core inwards, so it would seem that the energy term given above does not the potential energy of the system solenoid + iron core + magnetic field.
So what is this energy, and what is the force exerted on the iron core?

The sign issue is typical of these problems. It comes about because there are  two possible physical situations:

A superconducting coil  in which case the flux in the coil is fixed so   the current changes as the inductance changes. Thus  $L(x) I^2/2$ is not the correct energy. You need to express the energy in terms of the flux.

The current $I$ is fixed. In this   case, inserting or removing the coil changes the flux and so induces an emf ${\mathcal E}$. Consequently the  device keeping the current fixed has to do work (or have done on it) $= I \int {\mathcal E}(t)dt$. You need to include this work in the energy balance.


The same probem occurs in the more familiar example of whether the magnetic field tends to shrink or explode the coil. Just looking at the coil energy $LI^2/2$ suggests that the energy goes down when the coild shrinks, but in fact the coil tends to explode.

Thanks! Am I then right to assume that in your case 1) of a superconducting coil the iron core would indeed be pushed out of the coil? Moreover, if pushing the iron core in a distance x would require the work W in that case, would the current source in case 2) then deliver the energy 2W, so that you are left with a net gain of 2W - W = W?

I have not done the calculations in you  case (but I will -- a great exam problem!) , but for the coil exploding or shrinking case, both the superconductor and the constant-current-supply case, the outcomes are the same. The situation must the same also for your case. The energy method is merely a tool for simplifying the calcualtion. The forces are independent of how the magnetic field is created.
